# How to handle interrupts with `epoll_pwait`?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, epoll

I have a multi-threaded application that uses `epoll_pwait` to wait on reading from streams rather than busy polling and I need this application to be able to gracefully exit on an interrupt signal.

Currently I use `epoll_pwait` like (psuedo-code):

```
// SIGMASK = sigemptyset + sigaddset(SIGINT)

num = epoll_pwait(epoll_fd,&event_data,-1,&SIGMASK);
if num == -1 {
    if errno == EINTR {
        print("interrupt occurred");
    }
}
// read from stream
// ...
```

From my understanding it would be possible that an interrupt signal could occur before the `epoll_pwait` and then the process would enter the `epoll_pwait` and miss the interrupt signal.

My attempt at a solution still leaves a notable flaw:

```
static INTERRUPTED = false;
sigaction(SIGINT, /* function that sets `INTERRUPTED=true` */,null);

// SIGMASK = sigemptyset + sigaddset(SIGINT)

if INTERRUPTED {
    print("interrupt occurred");
}
// <--------------------- If the interrupt occurs here 
//                        both after this check and before
//                        entering the wait, it will miss it.
num = epoll_pwait(epoll_fd,&event_data,-1,&SIGMASK);
if num == -1 {
    if errno == EINTR {
        print("interrupt occurred");
    }
}
// read from stream
// ...
```

I'm stuck on this issue.

I have looked at [signalfd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) and [pthread_sigmask](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) but I still come back to this problem.

How should I solve this?

Can this be solved without a timeout?

Comment: I think you want to block the signal with `pthread_sigmask` before registering the handler and remove it from the signal mask in `epoll_pwait` (otherwise it won't trigger). You'd also want to mask the signal on other threads, so it gets handled here. If multiple threads need to wake up, you might want to use an `eventfd` (triggered by the signal handler) to wake them.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle signals, if it works for you, is to block all the ones you care about (e.g. with `sigprocmask`) and then use `signalfd` to receive them as file descriptor data.

Then, you don't need to worry about handling signals specially. You treat them as just another file descriptor.

If you insist on using signals as signals, then you need to block the signal whenever you are not calling `epoll_pwait`. The race condition you described is exactly the reason why functions like `epoll_pwait` exist. Otherwise you would just use `epoll_wait`. `epoll_pwait` allows you to unblock certain signals while waiting, with no race condition.

Blocked signals are not discarded, but delayed - the signal handler runs as soon as the signal becomes unblocked. The kernel considers that the signal is successfully delivered when it calls the signal handler or the signal is received by a `signalfd`, so if you read it from `signalfd`, then you don't need to worry about the handler being called as well.